# Converting a macro into a function

Tags: c++, c, macros

How do I convert the following macro into a function?

```
#define xtime(x)   ((x<<1) ^ (((x>>7) & 1) * 0x1b))
```

Comment: Do you know how to make a function? What about a parameter? Those are literally the only changes you have to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template<typename T>
T xtime(T x)
{
    return ((x<<1) ^ (((x>>7) & 1) * 0x1b));
}
```